# .net 6 Api Controller routes all returning 404

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I'm just trying to ascertain the correct routing setup for a .net 6 application.

In my program.cs I have this...

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DapperContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISupportService, SupportService>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
  
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

In my web API controller I have this...

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UsersController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpGet ("{id}")]
    public User GetUser(string id)
    {
        return _userService.GetUser(id);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return _userService.GetUsers();
    }
}
```

But when I call https://localhost:44427/api/users or https://localhost:44427/api/users/123 for example both 404.

But if I add this to the program.cs...

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

GetUsers works, but GetUser 404s?

Also another question in .net core 6, is it better to use conventional routing in program.cs or attribute based routing?

Comment: Have you tried adding Swagger to your project? It comes as standard with minimal API projects (not sure about others), and shows you the routes. That way you can see what ASP.NET thinks your routes are

Comment: Update to this, seems if I add app.MapControllers(); in program.cs the routes work, but GetUser still returns a 404?

Comment: Did you try Swagger? If so, what routes did it show?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I have tried installing the nuget package for swagger, but when running the app it just serves up the angular app, sorry I'm new to .net core, how can I amend the program.cs so that it serves up the swagger index.html instead of the angular app?

Comment: So I've got all the packages installed, and got the following in program.cs for swagger...

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});

  app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });

But going to /swagger doesn't work, I'm using a proxy server, so not sure if the proxy.conf.js file needs amending?

Comment: Your last question is opinion based and off topic on stackoverflow.com. Also asking multiple questions isnt a good idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

Updated pr request:

```cs
//UsersController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    public UsersController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet ("{id}")]
    public string GetUser(string id)
    {
        return "username";
    }

    [HttpGet ]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<string>(){"user2","user2"};
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
//program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// builder.Services.AddSingleton<DapperContext>();
// builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
// builder.Services.AddScoped<ISupportService, SupportService>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
  
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();

app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

If I call `http://localhost:5124/api/users` i get `public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()` `["user2","user2"]`

If I call `http://localhost:5124/api/users/1` i get `public string GetUser(string id)` `username`

---

Final go ...

If you add

```cs
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
```

Then it should work just as you have it with your `program.cs` even with the correct method name `GetUser`.

I really cant tell why it should'nt work on you machine. ...

> It works on my machine

Based on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Already done that, still doesn't work, have updated my question with the full program.cs file.

Comment: Updated my answer (the names are the same from a browser point of view. Try with `GetUserById`

Comment: Is this the correct way to do it over attribute based routing? Should I be removing the route and HttpGet attributes in my controllers and mapping them individually like this in the program.cs file?

Comment: If you go with attributes routing, then this is fine. If using controllers, i would go with your approach. I believe that having mapping in `program.cs` is just for use of minimal api for quickly spinning an API up to test against, og for minor website. 

for the full API experince, I woul go with controller based API

Comment: and yes @AnnL. this is just "sudo" code, or some small example withoout the userclasses injected.

Comment: Your comment about "users" vs. "user" -- are you saying that the API gets _confused_ about whether `GetUser` or `GetUsers` is meant?? That seems quite unlikely: the API is only going to care that they aren't the exact same string.

Comment: But, I was wondering whether his route defaulting the action to "Index" was going to have an impact, since he hasn't got an "Index" action/method.

Comment: Hey @AnnL. You are right. The naming of the method was not directly the issue. I just re-read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and found what need for setting up the `Conventional routing`

Comment: And in order to try to answer you question about index. given the use of _conventional routing_ the index will be based on the route e.g. `[Route("api/[controller]")]` will set that all `GET` without any action will be index. So having another `[HttpGet ]` would result in an exception. It needed to have an different _action_ e.g post/put/delete

Comment: @Peter are you able to update your answer with your working example along with the endpoint you're using to call GetUser? I have added app.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); but hitting the endpoint https://localhost:44427/api/users/123 still 404s

Comment: @orangejuice That's odd. I have updated my answer with a copy of what I have based on your code. Hope it helps 